# How to delete words from txt file, that exists on another txt file?

Tags: text-processing

File `a.txt` has about 100k words, each words is in new line

```
july.cpp
windows.exe
ttm.rar
document.zip
```

File `b.txt` has 150k words, one word by line - some words are from file `a.txt`, but some words are new:

```
july.cpp    
NOVEMBER.txt    
windows.exe    
ttm.rar    
document.zip    
diary.txt
```

How can I merge this files into one, delete all duplicate lines, and keep lines that are new (lines that exist in `a.txt` but don't exist in `b.txt`, and vice versa)?

Comment: Would you be happy to use python?

Comment: Looks like a homework from laboratory classes on University, am I right? Anyway, Your question is not about Ubuntu, please ask it on StackOverflow site.

Comment: @Tim, sure, why not

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki no, this is not for university homework, we have holiday now. I could done it in microsoft excel, but I don't want to use MS software.

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) would probably be a better place to ask

Comment: @MikołajBartnicki I saw your answer, it was in one line, but after refreshing page, answer disappeared.

Comment: Kasia, I have made a mistake in my answer, that is why I deleted it. I am working on a new one.

Comment: @Glutanimate This question is perfectly fine here.

Comment: @Seth I agree. I should have phrased my comment differently. What I meant was: If we were to argue about scope and the right SE site, Unix.SE would probably be more apt than SO.

Comment: @Glutanimate Ah, I'm sorry, I missed that comment somehow.

Comment: `sort -u a.txt b.txt`

Comment: there is trailing spaces in the second list, very hard to detect, can be a reason answers got so overcomplicated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a command to do this: `comm`. As stated in `man comm`, it is plain simple:

```
   comm -3 file1 file2
          Print lines in file1 not in file2, and vice versa.
```

Note that `comm` expects files contents to be sorted, so You must sort them before calling `comm` on them, just like that:

```
sort unsorted-file.txt > sorted-file.txt
```

So to sum up:

```
sort a.txt > as.txt

sort b.txt > bs.txt

comm -3 as.txt bs.txt > result.txt
```

After above commands, You will have expected lines in the `result.txt` file.

Comment: thank you, it works like a charm. PS. to zdjęcie z tłuczkiem na Twoim profilu jest fajne ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short python3 script, based on [Germar's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/502744/8232), which should accomplish this while retaining `b.txt`'s unsorted order.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

with open('a.txt', 'r') as afile:
    a = set(line.rstrip('\n') for line in afile)

with open('b.txt', 'r') as bfile:
    for line in bfile:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line not in a:
            print(line)
            # Uncomment the following if you also want to remove duplicates:
            # a.add(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
    a_txt = f.read()
a = a_txt.split('\n')
del(a_txt)

with open('b.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        b = f.readline().strip('\n ')
        if not len(b):
            break
        if not b in a:
            print(b)
```

Comment: Man, you are shooting a mosquito with a naval cannon!

Comment: :-) You're right. I missed the 'k' in 100k

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the coreutils `comm` command - `man comm`

```
NAME
       comm - compare two sorted files line by line

SYNOPSIS
       comm [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2

DESCRIPTION
       Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.

       With  no  options,  produce  three-column  output.  Column one contains
       lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to  FILE2,  and
       column three contains lines common to both files.

       -1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)

       -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)

       -3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```

So for example you can do

```
$ comm -13 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
diary.txt
NOVEMBER.txt
```

(lines unique to `b.txt`)